# iOS app (this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource)

Tags: ios, uitableview, key-value

I'm making an iPhone app, and I'm working at this TableViewController, but when testing, I get this error, and I don't really know what to do with it:

```
2012-01-13 13:45:32.947 HandHistory Reviews[3422:707] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<SessionsTableViewController 0x191cb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dataSource.'
```

Anyone got an idea?

This is my SessionTableViewController.m file:

```
#import "SessionsTableViewController.h"
#import "Session.h"

@interface SessionsTableViewController()

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *sessions;

@end

@implementation SessionsTableViewController

@synthesize sessions = _sessions;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSMutableArray *sessions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Looking for files
    // Finding the Documents directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];

    // Looping through each file in the directory
    for (NSString *file in directoryContent)
    {
        NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

        Session *session = [[Session alloc] initWithName:file andContents:contents];

        [sessions addObject:session];
    }

    self.sessions = sessions;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sessions count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Session Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [[self.sessions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d hands", 10];

    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

Comment: check out NSLog the session first

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you've wired things up in interface builder incorrectly. It appears you have attached something to an outlet called `dataSource` in your `SessionsTableViewController`. It looks like you probably wanted to do it the other way round as I assume you have a table view in `SessionsTableViewController`.

So, you need to attach the `dataSource` property of your table view to your instance of `SessionsTableViewController` (probably "File's Owner" in your case), rather than the other way round.

Comment: I see, I've set my SessionsTableViewController as custom class for my TableView instead of my TableViewController, thanks, this is what I was looking for, everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occur when outlets are not connected properly. In my case checking outlets connection would always solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you haven't specified the wrong app in the box labeled Module (just under Class).  This is in the Identity Inspector in the UI Builder.

You shouldn't normally have anything specified as Module, as it defaults to a grayed out entry labeled "current....", meaning its available in all apps. But, if you have specified an app here, the UI item won't be available to any other apps in your project, giving you the subject error message when you try to run other apps.

That was my problem...

Comment: If this comment answers the question, it's not immediately clear how. Consider rewording?

Comment: I don'n know how else I can reword it.  If you have anything specified in Module, you will get the error the OP specified when you try to build another module.